# xtype = html5smartimage in sightly

Tags: java, dialog, aem, sightly

I am using an html5smartimage in my aem dialog. Below is the code that i have added in dialog.xml.

```
<image
jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
xtype="html5smartimage"
name="./imgFile"
fieldLabel="Image"
style="border: 2px dashed #ccc;"
height="200"
ddGroups="[media]"
fieldDescription="To use a customized icon please upload it to the dam and add it here."
allowUpload="{Boolean}false"
requestSuffix=".img.png"
renditionSuffix="/_jcr_content/renditions/original"
cropParameter="./imageCrop"
fileNameParameter="./fileName"
fileReferenceParameter="./fileReference"
rotateParameter="./imageRotate" />
```

I added these lines of code in my component and still i am getting "theres no data". I am able to drag and drop the image fine, but reading it seems to be the only problem

```
<sly data-sty-test.imgFileObj="${properties.imgFile}"></sly>

<div data-sly-test="${!imgFileObj}">
theres no data
</div>
<div data-sly-test="${imgFileObj}">
theres is data
</div>
```

I checked everywhere but to no avail. So any help with this would be appreciated. Also the end goal is to get the image url.

Answer (score 0):

**html5smartimage** does not save the data by the "name" property. It supports lot of settings, so based on how the image was configured you can expect the data to be saved in different ways.

If an image is dragged and dropped into the widget, it would be saved with the property name associated with "fileReferenceParameter". In your case it would be `data-sty-test.imgFileObj="${properties.fileReference}`.

If an image was uploaded it will create a child node with the name provided in **fileNameParameter**.